# Rounding errors in Ruby matrix implementation

Tags: ruby, matrix, precision

I'm doing a bit 'o matrix algebra in ruby. When testing the results, I'm seeing what I can only assume is a rounding error.

All I'm doing is multiplying 3 matrices, but the values are fairly small:

```
c_xy:
[0.9702957262759965, 0.012661213742314235, -0.24159035004964077]
[0, 0.9986295347545738, 0.05233595624294383]
[0.24192189559966773, -0.050781354673095955, 0.9689659697053497]

i2k = Matrix[[8.1144E-06, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 8.1144E-06, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 8.1144E-06]]

c_yx:
[0.9702957262759965, 0, 0.24192189559966773]
[0.012661213742314235, 0.9986295347545738, -0.050781354673095955]
[-0.24159035004964077, 0.05233595624294383, 0.9689659697053497]
```

What I'm trying to do is `c_xy * i2k * c_yx`. Here's what I expect (this was done in Excel):

```
8.1144E-06  0   2.11758E-22
0   8.1144E-06  0
2.11758E-22 -5.29396E-23    8.1144E-06
```

And what I get:

```
[8.1144e-06, 1.3234889800848443e-23, 6.352747104407253e-22]
[0.0, 8.114399999999998e-06, -5.293955920339377e-23]
[2.117582368135751e-22, 0.0, 8.1144e-06]
```

As you can see, the first column matches, as does the diagonal. But then (in r,c indexing) (0,1) is wrong (though approaching 0), (0,2) is very wrong, and (1,2) and (2,1) seem to be transposed. I thought it had something to do with the`8.1144e-6` value, and tried wrapping it in a `BigDecimal` to no avail.

Any ideas on places I can look? I'm using the standard Ruby Matrix library

*edit*

here's the code.

```
phi1 = 0.24434609527920614
phi2 = 0.05235987755982988

i2k = Matrix[[8.1144E-06, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, 8.1144E-06, 0.0],
                [0.0, 0.0, 8.1144E-06]]

c_x = Matrix[[1, 0, 0],
             [0, Math.cos(phi2), Math.sin(phi2)],
             [0, -Math.sin(phi2), Math.cos(phi2)]]

c_y = Matrix[[Math.cos(phi1), 0, -Math.sin(phi1)],
             [0, 1, 0],
             [Math.sin(phi1), 0, Math.cos(phi1)]]

c_xy = c_y * c_x
c_yx = c_xy.transpose

c_xy * i2k * c_yx
```

Comment: You arranged the question very well. The only thing I am missing your attempted code. That's also needed to validate, what you are saying.

Comment: the Matrix library overloads standard operators, so... What I'm trying to do is `c_xy * i2k * c_yx`

Comment: With numbers this small, I'm not surprised that a floating point error is getting you.  You may want to consider taking the logs of the values, adding together and then inverse log to get better precision.

Comment: @RobDiMarco - this is just a step in a fairly long chain that I don't want to mess with. Is there a way to increase precision at the expense of CPU / Memory?

Comment: I would sooner trust ruby over Excel :) Have you tried testing with just multiplying 2 matrices? This will help isolate where the problem is. Also showing the code as @ArupRakshit suggested will help. We're not sure if the matrices are being initialized properly, etc.

Comment: I have. The intermediate step (`c_xy * i2k`) matches excel. The values I'm showing here are from printing the intermediate matrices, so it's what Ruby sees. Like I said - this a step in the middle of a convoluted chain of operations

Comment: why the -1? why the close?

Comment: Probably because you didn't show the code - hard to find the source of the error that way and leaves us guessing. (Btw I didn't downvote or vote to close.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i2k` is equal to the identity matrix times 8.1144E-06. This simplifies the answer to:

```
c_xy * i2k * c_yx = 8.1144E-06 * c_xy * c_yx
```

However since `c_yx = c_xy.transpose` and `c_xy` is a rotation matrix, the transpose of any rotation matrix is its inverse. So `c_xy * c_yx` is the identity matrix, and thus the *exact* answer is 8.1144E-06 times the identity matrix.

---

Here is one way to calculate `c_xy * c_yx` without using the matrix algebra a priori:

```
require 'matrix'
require 'pp'

phi1 = 14 * Math::PI/180
phi2 =  3 * Math::PI/180

c_x = Matrix[
    [1,0,0],
    [0,  Math.cos(phi2), Math.sin(phi2) ],
    [0, -Math.sin(phi2), Math.cos(phi2) ] ]

c_y = Matrix[
    [Math.cos(phi1), 0, -Math.sin(phi1) ],
    [0,1,0],
    [Math.sin(phi1), 0,  Math.cos(phi1) ] ]

c_xy = c_y * c_x
c_yx = c_xy.transpose

product = c_xy * c_yx

pp *product

clone = *product
puts "\nApplying EPSILON:"
product.each_with_index do |e,i,j|
  clone[i][j] = 0 if e.abs <= Float::EPSILON
end
pp clone
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 0.0, 2.7755575615628914e-17]
[0.0, 0.9999999999999999, -6.938893903907228e-18]
[2.7755575615628914e-17, -6.938893903907228e-18, 0.9999999999999999]

Applying EPSILON:
[1.0, 0, 0]
[0, 0.9999999999999999, 0]
[0, 0, 0.9999999999999999]
```

which one can then surmise *should* be the identity matrix. This uses `Float::EPSILON` which is about `2.220446049250313e-16` in order to set values that have an absolute value no more than this equal to 0. These kinds of approximations are inevitable in floating point calculations; one must evaluate the appropriateness of these approximations on a case-by-case basis.

An alternative is to do [symbolic computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html) where possible rather than numeric.

Comment: i've added the code. for one, the order of operations is different between multiple and the other options. Given the fact that the numbers don't seem to change, it looks like it's wrong everywhere.

Comment: @kolosy Your first `i2k` is different from your second `i2k`. Which should it be?

Comment: updated - typo the first time around. like i said, this is part of a long string of stuff that i'm carving out for the question. the numbers pasted here were wrong, the end result is still as written.

Comment: @kolosy `i2k` (the new value) is just 8.1144E-06 times the identity matrix. So the answer is equivalent to `8.1144E-06 * c_xy * c_yx`. Hope that helps.

Comment: nice catch on the identity, but no change.

Comment: but position (1,2) is not accurate - it should be 0.

Comment: @kolosy Added a link to WolframAlpha to calculate this based on the original degree values of 14 and 3. I would trust this calculation.

Comment: thanks. though there doesn't seem to be an answer here, it does look like a precision issue, not a code issue. i'm marking this as the answer. fwiw, your answer doesn't match what i get from matlab, which doesn't match what i get from excel. *sigh*

Comment: @kolosy I made mistakes in the Wolfram Alpha link - sorry about that. Answer has been updated. Yes I agree these turned out to just be rounding errors. The final answer is just `i2k` itself.

Answer (score -1):

Floating point numbers have a precision:

```
puts Float::DIG # => 15
```

That's the number of decimal digits a Float can have on my, and probably your system. Numbers smaller than 1E-15 can not be represented with a float. You could try [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) for arbitrary large precision.

Comment: well, clearly smaller numbers *can* be represented, since I'm getting values in the 1E-22 range. Number of digits is separate from absolute magnitude. `Float::DIG` is 15 on my system as well.

Comment: As a float consists of a mantissa (with up to `Float::DIG` decimal digits of accuracy or `Float::MANT_DIG` bits) and an exponent (`Float::MIN_EXP=1021`, so the smallest number will be `2^-1021`) your "smallest possible number above 0" is much less than one would think considering just the mantissa. This has *exactly* been designed this way in order to make very small numbers possible. But as you are multiplying positive and negative numbers you may fall prey to cancellation.